# Installing Mercurial on Debian Squeeze: hg gives an "couldn't find mercurial libraries" error

Tags: mercurial, debian

After seemingly-successful installation on Debian Squeeze(via `apt-get install mercurial`), hg refuses to start, giving this error:

```
root@pe-test:/tmp/example.com# hg
abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in [/usr/bin /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2 /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6]
(check your install and PYTHONPATH)
```

The only way I can get it working is to install mercurial via `pip install`, but I don't think its a proper way.

Comment: I'v installed Mercurial on plenty of Debian boxes and never had a problem. How do you installed Pyhton ? Your python looking path seems strange to me. Did the mercurial-common package was also installed ? If I were you, I'd try to reinstall python or at least check if you didn't change something to your Python install, the problem doesn't seem related directly to Mercurial

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found [this bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=646546) in the Debian bug tracker:  which describes exactly the same issue. The following steps resolved the problem :

> debsums -c python-support showed no differences, **but reinstalling
>   python-support before reinstalling mercurial and mercurial-common
>   actually solved the issue**.

So you can try the following:

```
apt-get --reinstall install python-support
apt-get --reinstall install mercurial mercurial-common
```

The problem is apparently that python-support triggers aren't run correctly, but the bug doesn't give any reason as of why. Hopefully the comands below will also solve the issue for you.

**Update**

As said in multiple comments, running `dpkg-reconfigure` seems to be sufficient:

```
dpkg-reconfigure python-support
```

Comment: Thanks. You've helped me. This solved the issue:
    
    dpkg-reconfigure python-support

Comment: Actually just `dpkg-reconfigure python-support` did resolve it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your python version is same... 
Or create a link in `/usr/bin/python` at proper version, problem will be resolved.

`root:~# which python`

`/usr/bin/python`

`root:~# ll /usr/bin/python`

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Dec  9  2015 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7*`

`root:~#`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message, but the solution in krtek's answer did not work for me. My problem was that I had several versions of python installed. Choosing the right python version via `sudo update-alternatives --config python` solved the problem for me.